# Random colour in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make some random colours in WPF.

```
Random r = new Random();
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Title = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MainWindow mainwindow_1 = new MainWindow();
   Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r.Next(1,255),r.Next(1,255),r.Next(1,233)));
   mainwindow_1.txtbox_1.Background = brush; 
   mainwindow_1.Show(); 
}
```

If I enter normal values like 1,2,3 ... ect in Color.FromRgb() it works but why doesn't random work?

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: "Doesn't work" basically provides no information. We can't help you if you don't describe the symptoms.

Comment: Have you checked what your r is returning?

Comment: invalid arguments, maybe i should convert...

Comment: yea just type cast them to bytes

Comment: Ok it works fine now. Just convert to byte. Thank you.

Comment: "invalid arguments, maybe i should convert" still doesn't tell us exactly what you're seeing. It sounds like you're getting a compile-time error - so provide that *exact* error message (copy and paste it) in the question, including what line it's on. Please remember this for next time you ask a question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Color.FromRgb` accepts bytes as arguments, so you must cast your values:

```cs
Random r = new Random();
Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)r.Next(1, 255), 
                  (byte)r.Next(1, 255), (byte)r.Next(1, 233)));
```

Comment: When generating multiple random colors, ensure that the same `Random` object is used to be able to generate distinct colors.

Answer (score 2):

This line is passing `int` arguments to a function that wants `byte` arguments:

```
Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r.Next(1,255),r.Next(1,255),r.Next(1,233)));
```

Cast the arguments to bytes to avoid the compile error:

```
Brush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb((byte)r.Next(1,255),(byte)r.Next(1,255),(byte)r.Next(1,233)));
```